# Methods to get the id of the clicked on checkbox not working

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-events

When clicking on any of the subtree-checkboxes under  Admin, none of the methods to retrieve and show the id of the clicked on element in my js work.
All attempts return undefined.
What is required to get the id then?

```
            <div class="tree" style="border: currentColor; border-image: none; height: 1200px; -ms-overflow-y: hidden;">
                <ul class="nav nav-list" style="border: currentColor; border-image: none;">
                    <li>
                        <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MMenu_DTID1">
                            <span class="checkbox MMTree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted1" class="MMTree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted1" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
                            <input name="MM_IsPermitted1" type="hidden" value="false">
                            Admin
                        </span>
                        <ul class="nav nav-list collapse" id="MMenu_DTID1" style="padding-left: 20px;">
                            <li>
                                <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#S_menu1">
                                    <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted1" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted1" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
                                    <input name="SM_IsPermitted1" type="hidden" value="false">
                                    Users
                                </span>
                                <ul class="nav nav-list collapse" id="S_menu1" style="padding-left: 60px;">
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="accordion-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#S_menu11">
                                            <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red">
                                              <input name="SM_IsPermitted11"  class="subtree-checkbox styled red" 
                                                     id="SM_IsPermitted11" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="2">
                                            </span>
                                            <input name="SM_IsPermitted11" type="hidden" value="false">                                                 
                                             testGetID
                                        </span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

```js
$(function ()
{
 $(".subtree-checkbox").click(function (e)
 {
        var idx = $(this).attr('id');
     var idxx = $(this).prop('id');
     alert("e.target.id = " + e.target.id);
            alert("id = " + idx);
     alert("idxx = " + idxx);
     });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're hooking the event on a `span`, not on the checkbox. Hook the checkbox instead, and use `this.id` to get the `id`:

```
$(".subtree-checkbox input[type=checkbox]").click(function (e) {
    var id = this.id;
    // ...
});
```

Or if you need to hook the span instead, use `find` to find the checkbox:

```
$(".subtree-checkbox").click(function (e) {
    var id = $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("id");
    // ...
});
```

Or (a bit less jQuery) `querySelector`:

```
$(".subtree-checkbox").click(function (e) {
    var id = this.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]").id;
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks..The Learning curve is steep, but great to have people who can and are willing to help. will accept as answer in some 6 minutes.